# li elements moving about in Chrome (display: inline-block)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Please see this page: http://access.mwjt.co.uk/feedback/?s=hmmm

When viewed in Chrome, occasionally the 3 pictures are in the correct place, but usually some or all of them jump down to a lower position. (hitting refresh shows the error as the page displays differently each time)

Can anyone shed any light on this bug please?

Many thanks! Mike

Comment: Have you tried creating a stripped down repro of the problem? Take out elements (such as the javascript) until you get a much more concise version of the page that is easier to troubleshoot. If taking something out stops the bug from happening then look carefully at what you've take out and whether that is actually your problem. I tried saving it on my computer to do this but then it immediately stopped failing. Not sure whether that was because of subtle changes from the save process or due to running it from a local file rather than a web server (dunno if chrome may treat them differently).

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chris, managed to quickly troubleshoot it by doing this. Turns out the image sizes were being resized by webkit and Chrome wasn't always consistently happy with this. Setting image heights as px solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the image sizes were being resized by webkit and Chrome wasn't always consistently happy with this. Setting image heights as px solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have some invalid HTML markup going on there.

Firstly, wrapping the form within a fieldset? should be the otherway around, Form > Fieldset.

Also, after the `</ul>` you have a `<p></div>` combo going on. this is probably causing the page to break.

Comment: The closing tag for a `<P>` element is in fact optional and there was an open div before the `<ul>`. I've not actually fully tested out the validity of the page but am just responding to what you've implied is invalid but is in fact not. The fieldset thing totally is though. :)

Comment: Personally I would never open a `<p>` element without closing it. Validation result is here http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Faccess.mwjt.co.uk%2Ffeedback%2F%3Fs%3Dhmmm

Comment: Jsut noticed as I look at the validation page that it is meant to be XHTML so in that case I am wrong and close tags are always compulsory. And yes, it is good practice to close all tags you open but in general HTML the parser shouldn't care about unclosed <p> tags as long as they are properly unclosed (as opposed to something like `<div><p></div></p>` where the last close p is invalid even thought it is meant to be a match for the opening p).

Comment: Wow - thanks for the comments so far, will correct the markup errors and see it that sorts it. No issues in IE bizarrely!